# OpenVPN - Can't ping LAN machines on remote side

Tags: openvpn

```
local 193.xxx.xxx.2
push "route 192.186.0.0 255.255.255.0"
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-crypt tc.key
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "block-outside-dns"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
explicit-exit-notify
```

How am I able to make it so my OpenVPN connection can ping other machines in the LAN using `192.168.0.0/24` range.

ip a

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:00:00:20:a1:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 193.xxx.xxx.2/24 brd 193.138.195.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.186.0.2/24 brd 192.186.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ff:fe20:a102/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.8.0.1/24 brd 10.8.0.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1f00:d21:971c:27a/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip r

```
default via 193.xxx.xxx.1 dev eth0 proto static
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.2
193.xxx.xxx.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 193.xxx.xxx.2
```

Client config

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 193.xxx.xxx.2 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
verb 3
```

Comment: from the documentation and examples, `push route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0`

Comment: Add that in the server.conf?

Comment: Added that it did not work but I found ```push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"``` but I can't ping anything in ```192.168.0.0/24``` except for the IP it's using (```192.168.0.2```)

Comment: I think the issue is with tun0 being used? ```3: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.8.0.1/24 brd 10.8.0.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7b51:345e:8f8c:b159/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever```

Comment: ```default via 193.xxx.xxx.1 dev eth0 proto static
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1```

Comment: is that server or client config your posting in comments now? add it to the question, nicely formatted, for readability

Comment: Updated it now.